# Powershell dealing with long path works on one system , but not the other

Tags: powershell

**Not working system**

Path starts with  \\?\C:\Users...

copy-item -path $sf -Destination $tf

I get the bellow errors message

copy-item : Illegal characters in path

I remove the leading \\?\ it will stop complaining.

Also an issue with Compress Archive
I call
Compress-Archive -Path "\\?\$($RootDir...

It returns no errors , but no zip file get created.

This is win 11 21H2

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                         
----                           -----                                                         
PSVersion                      5.1.22000.282                                                 
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                       
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                       
BuildVersion                   10.0.22000.282                                                
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                               
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                           
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**On the system this works on**

This is win 10 21H2

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                       
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1320                                                                              
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                     
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                     
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1320                                                                             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                             
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                         
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                         
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Please show the full `Copy-Item` command, including a full, literal path that triggers the error.

Comment: $sf = "$($f.FullName)"
   $tf = "\\?\$($tagetPath)\$($f.Name)"
   copy-item -path $sf -Destination $tf

Comment: Where are the "\\?\" characters coming from? Can you post as [mre] how you get those ?

Comment: The characters are added on purpose to support long path.  Path that are longer then MAX_PATH 260 characters.  A windows thing witch PowerShell supports. 

Here is one article:  https://blog.matthewbrowne.com/blog/dealing-with-long-paths-in-powershell/?msclkid=d5f31ff3b1d311ec92d55131479175a3

Comment: Re full command: please add one directly to your question, not in comments. Also, show a _literal_ path - i.e. what the above _expands to_ (anonymized, if needed).

Comment: I believe you **must** use `-LiteralPath` instead of the default `-Path` for `"\\?\"` paths on cmdlets that support it. Otherwise the `?` character is treated as a wildcard

Comment: Enable long paths system-wide, so you no longer need to deal with prehistoric `\\?\ ` prefix, instead you can just use normal paths: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

Comment: Enabling long path system wide works.  This solved my problems. Thanks you Zett42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply by zett42 is the answer

Enable long paths system-wide, so you no longer need to deal with prehistoric \?\  prefix, instead you can just use normal paths: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later –
zett42